# How to reshape data to a 2D CNN input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

everyone!

I've a problem with data reshaping to fed my 2D CNN.
My model is

```
cnn_input = Input(shape=(1, 800, 26), name='cnn_input')

cnn_conv1 = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(cnn_input)
cnn_batch_norm1 = BatchNormalization()(cnn_conv1)
cnn_relu1 = ReLU()(cnn_batch_norm1)
cnn_pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), data_format='channels_first')(cnn_relu1)
cnn_drop1 = Dropout(0.2)(cnn_pool1)

cnn_conv2 = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(cnn_drop1)
cnn_batch_norm2 = BatchNormalization()(cnn_conv2)
cnn_relu2 = ReLU()(cnn_batch_norm2)
cnn_pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), data_format='channels_first')(cnn_relu2)
cnn_drop2 = Dropout(0.2)(cnn_pool2)

cnn_conv3 = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(cnn_drop2)
cnn_batch_norm3 = BatchNormalization()(cnn_conv3)
cnn_relu3 = ReLU()(cnn_batch_norm3)
cnn_pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), data_format='channels_first')(cnn_relu3)
cnn_drop3 = Dropout(0.2)(cnn_pool3)

cnn_conv4 = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(cnn_drop3)
cnn_batch_norm4 = BatchNormalization()(cnn_conv4)
cnn_relu4 = ReLU()(cnn_batch_norm4)
cnn_pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4), strides=(4, 4), data_format='channels_first')(cnn_relu4)
cnn_drop4 = Dropout(0.2)(cnn_pool4)

cnn_conv5 = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(cnn_drop4)
cnn_batch_norm5 = BatchNormalization()(cnn_conv5)
cnn_relu5 = ReLU()(cnn_batch_norm5)
cnn_pool5 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4), strides=(4, 4), data_format='channels_first')(cnn_relu5)
cnn_drop5 = Dropout(0.2)(cnn_pool5)

cnn_flat = Flatten()(cnn_drop5)
cnn_output = Dense(256)(cnn_flat)

cnn = Model(inputs=cnn_input, outputs=cnn_output, name='PCNNA')
```

and the shape of my data is

```
print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)
>>> (800, 26) (200, 26) (800,) (200,)
```

But before fit the model, I made the following reshape :

```
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (1, 800, 26))
```

and when I run `fit()` I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected pcnna_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 800, 26)
```

Comment: You are using a 2D convolutional layers so your input must be 4D as opposed to 3D, normally in the following format - (batch_size, channels, rows, cols).

Comment: A lot of dimensions in this code does not make sense! (800 , 26) means you have 800 samples of length 26 (1D) and y size of 800 means each sample has output vector of size  1  but cnn_output expects an array of size 256. Back to your error,  you need to provide batch dimension in your X_train and X_test. Since your input is (1, 800, 26) then your X_train has to be size of (#samples, 1, 800, 26).